# Can I submit student work with classroom API?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to make a program to submit my google classroom work quicker (as a student). I've read the google classroom API but it's very oriented to teachers and I don't know if my idea is posible.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible.

The reason, unless you used the same program that created the assignment, you will not have the proper developer authentication permissions.

You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn

If you want to experiment and learn how the process goes, possibly even test different approaches, I recommend this post:
https://yagisanatode.com/2020/05/13/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/